# Bioengineering the ultimate predator

Tags: biology, creature-design

### Bioengeneering the ultimate hybrid predator

Much like the Indominus Rex from Jurassic World I seek to create the ultimate killing machine. However these hybrids that we often see in science-fiction resemble their natural counterparts too much. So I wish to create something that is both powerful and unique, even though it is built from real animals from earth. Do not worry about the creature killing its creators, as the finished product will be launched into the wild.

To give you a bit of direction, imagine the ultimate prey. A fast armadillo/porcupine that has poison resistance and very acute senses, with heights varying from cat sized to cow sized. As for its environment something akin to a rainforest where there is a lot of competition, or any other harsh environment for that matter. An ultimate predator should be able to hunt anything, big or small.

If my question is missing information, comment and editing will ensue.

Comment: How big is the armadillo? And from an evolutionary perspective the ultimate predator would disguise itself as the surroundings like a Catfish around a food source and just wait for its prey to come to it. Hunting is a very energetic thing compared to waiting for your prey to come to you. The ultimate predator would be energy efficient... but I dont think that is the purpose of your question. You want the ultimate chase-and-murder predator if I am reading it right that scares the hell out of humans.

Comment: "Ultimate predator" is like "ultimate tool".  A hammer is a sweet tool for driving nails or fighting, mediocre for digging, not very helpful for cooking, useless for electronics work.  The genetic fitness of a predator (a measure of ultimateness?) depends on ecosystem, prey, and reproductive capacity.

Comment: I presume its purpose in the story is to provide some kind of menace. But, what _kind_ of menace? The sort where the protagonists engage in some sort of hide-and-seek, perhaps?

Comment: "Unstoppable" is way too far of a reach. Humans have literally killed just about every kind of living creature we've ever encountered as a species, and for most of that history, have done so with little more than rocks and sticks. There is no such thing as an "unstoppable" creature, enough men with enough rocks and enough sticks can kill literally anything.

Comment: ultimate prey would be more like the african porcupine, where else does such a small mammal survive amongst lions, hyenas and so many other top tier predators

Comment: I can't help feeling like the answer involves teaching what happens when a man and a women get together, like each other, and produce a child.  Then teach the child how to use a gun and they become an apex predator.

Comment: @Trevor...teach the kid how to use a rock and a stick is more like it.

Answer (score 7):

For killing that particular prey?

A very big pitcher plant that emits the scent of a superdillo in heat. Amorous superdillo runs up at a reckless speed, falls in, and is too heavily armoured to get out of the super sloppy death pot.

Seriously though: the reason we see so much specialisation in nature is because the ‘ultimate’ anything doesn’t really exist. Predator/prey relationships tend to be a complex arms race of specialising to catch your prey while not overspecialising so much that your specific prey is the only thing you can catch (unless your prey is abundant, see anteaters).

With that in mind: the thing that makes a predator truly ‘ultimate’ is adaptability (for learning how to hunt new things) and perseverance (so you don’t give up on hunting the new things). What animal has those two things in spades? Oh. Wait. Us.

Seriously. A human being would just walk after your superdillo, carefully avoiding all the other things they know would kill them. If the superdillo flees it will tire, and eventually the human will catch and kill it (We’re very good at walking things to death). If it turns to fight it’s going to run headfirst into whatever tasty death trap the human has conjured for it (maybe even some domesticated ‘ultimate’ predators). If it hides we can track it. If it hunkers down we can build a fire around it and cook it where ever it’s gone to ground.

Basically what I’m saying is that your ultimate predator is just a human being with a lot of local knowledge. Though you could make them scarier by making them smarter and removing the responses that make us empathise with non-human species. “What cute eyes and waggy tail? All I see is a hunting tool. Or possibly lunch.” That way if it isn’t an exploitable resource it’s prey. And prey gets eaten.

But even geniuses with skewed ideas on animal rights can accidentally slip and fall into a giant pitcher plant if they’re not careful, so maybe ‘ultimate’ isn’t so ultimate after all.

Comment: Did you completely ignore the bioengineered part? On a side note I was not asking for a superdillo (gosh I love that name) specific predator, but was merely using as a reference as to what defense mechanisms an ultimate predator should be able to counter.

Comment: @LiveInAmber: Pretty much. Even using nothing but sticks and fire humanity has managed to become *the* apex predator in every terrestrial environment we’ve come across. Given enough time and a bit of knowledge of the environment we find ways to kill pretty much everything that crosses our path without any need for further bioengineering. Though if you were to go for bioengineering: make smarter people and engineer empathy for anything that isn’t human out of them. I’ll add a section.

Comment: I sure does sound like that pitcher plant ate it all, sounds like an ultimate predator to me :D

Comment: You could presumably bioengineer a human to be a little bit stronger and smarter, if you have some sort of artificial womb, so it won't be restricted to fit through a normal human birth canal. But I wouldn't go too far. It has to look sufficiently similar to a human that humans will willingly raise it (so it gets all our knowledge), and it has to pass for human enough to not be chased out of a hunting goods store.

Comment: @Zwuwdz: Hunting goods store? I think you underestimate how much can be done with some sharp sticks and a group of friends as smart as you are. Also: if they’re intelligent and have higher endurance they’re arguably more lethal than smarter and stronger. Smarter means confronting them is almost always lethal, so if they can chase you until you can’t run any more they always win, while if they’re stronger but sleep more you might be able to escape.... Hooray for pursuit predation!

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a very muscular torso with 4 limbs at the “corners” that have 3 joints each. One of the joints can be locked in position for running horse like or they can be unlocked to provide extreme flexibility slightly trunk or tentacle like. But each ends in a vicious set of claw/talons that can be retracted for running a bit like a cat.

The creature has no head, but above the centre of the torso is a domed bulge that acts as a sonar receptor and also contains a small organ for generating ultrasonic screams, below the torso is a huge beak. The creature can climb well and likes to hide in trees in the dark lower canopy. Its skin is similar to that of an octopus in that it can mimic its surroundings. It likes to let its prey walk underneath it then it jumps down on top of it, but it can also run well if needed and it can use its ultrasonic sense to “see” in the dark.

The torso is around 4 foot across and each limb is 4 foot long.

I suspect that such a creature would not defy any natural laws and given the correct environment, sufficient time and the correct selection pressures could evolve based on DNA biochemistry (or at least could theoretically be engineered). However exactly what sequences of DNA would be needed is an impossible question to answer with current understanding of genetics and biochemistry.

Comment: I love how you decided to build from the ground up! Also some slight touches would be other senses than sonar like infrared and an acute sense of smell.

Answer (score 2):

When I see this type of question, my mind always jumps to a [Xenomorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(creature_in_Alien_franchise)) style creature. Agile, smart, tough, acute senses, toxic if you try to fight back... I think that ticks just about all your requests.

Feel free to adapt it as you want, like actually giving it eyes. One thing I thought would be cool is if it directly lays eggs inside its victim, which then hatch into chestbursters. No need to go through the facehugger stage.

---

A different approach would be to not just have one creature, but a swarm of locust-like insects. Quite difficult to fight against, can fit through tiny spaces due to each bug being quite small. You could also design different roles within the swarm:

- Stingers: very fast and have a sting which delivers a neurotoxin that would slowly paralyse whatever they sting, allowing the rest of the swarm to catch up,
- Chewers: strong jaws and acidic saliva allow these ones to chew through most armour and structures. Can also dig termite-style nests for the swarm to hide in when waiting for its next prey to turn up,
- Mothers: sort of as I described above, these ones lay eggs in their victims to ensure the swarm's descendance

You can add whatever you feel would be necessary for your particular setting, but I think that these would make for some pretty fearsome predators.

Comment: Not long ago I had the exact same idea. You sir are a man of culture.

Answer (score 1):

So you want a Bio-Engineered Murder Machine.  This is not going to be Sugar and Spice or Snips and Snails and puppy dog tails.

Lets build from the basics, not specific features. What has made the ultimate predator in nature so far and why was it so good?  As Joe Bloggs says, the ultimate Apex Predator on earth is *Homo Sapiens*.  So lets build the super predator from things that made Us so very good at killing things.  Then we can build on bells and whistles

**Endurance**  Lets face it, We are the Terminator to other species on this planet.  We just keep on coming.  The prey runs fast, but it can't run far enough.  They just barely get their breath back and there we are.  They can't hide, and eventually they give up out of exhaustion.  That silly naked ape with a stick is more than a match for all kinds of prey.

**Cooperation**  We succeed because we don't get all solitary.  Ever notice that pack hunters tend to be more successful overall.  It's why Wolves were the most successful apex predator in the New World even though they are not as tough as Bears or as flexible as Mountain Lions.  They easily take prey much larger than themselves because they work together and don't drive each other off (much).  Humankind is also successful in a wide range of environments because in addition to being pink squishy terminators, we can set and spring ambushes and drive prey toward a place they can be more easily killed.

**Intelligence and Tools**  I'm kind of broadening this one out to include altering the landscape, using weapons, using the landscape as a weapon.  Humans do all of this and you want your super predator to do this as well.  They should be able to spot the best places to ambush prey, take the time to modify the landscape to perfect it, and then drive the prey to the ambush site.

**Varied Diet**  This is important, you need to be able to live through times when adequate prey is not around, so you need to be able to eat a broad variety of things.  Consider the housecat.  *felis domesticus* can survive on a huge variety of prey animals, from bugs to frogs, to fish, to birds to rodents.....and so on.  Humans are the same.

Now for some fun bits.  I imagine your super predator looking a lot like Anthropromorphized Animals seen in Anime.  The one that clearly stands in my mind is from "Love Death and Robots" on Netflix.  Hind legs ending in a paw with semi-retractable claws.

The general shape of the whole leg would be similar to an elongated large cat leg.

Long Muscular tail, possibly prehensile, but with the main focus being on balance.

Overall posture of the animal would be upright, with a preference for walking on hind legs.

Could easily go to all fours for running very fast, but will stay upright for moving at slow to moderate speeds and for long distances.

Trunk of the animal would be narrow waisted with a deep chest for excellent lung capacity and maximum endurance.

Shoulders should accommodate a large range of motion in the arms.

Hands should have opposable thumbs and good gripping surfaces.  In addition, retractable claws would be a huge bonus.

Head should be fairly large for both cranial capacity and to accommodate large eyes (the better to see you with).  Ears should be directional like a cat or dog.  And the Jaw...Shape it like a Pit Bull to give you a balance between sharp teeth and crushing jaw strength.

Add to this a short fur pelt and some amount of fat reserves to give it the ability to keep warm in the cold but not overheat too much in the warmer climates.  Add to this a mottled, random pattern, somewhat like a tortoiseshell cat (those little buggers are really hard to see in the dark).

So you have a tool using endurance predator that will kill the Superdillo after he bit it's leg off after a very long chase into a place of his choosing that was prepped beforehand by his buddies.  He and his buddies flip the Superdillo over, gut it with their claws, and joint it out with tools they made. Remove the heavy shell to use in further tools or armor, maybe to make an impromptu raft to help get out of the pitcher plant.

Comment: Excellent answer. However the human part doesn't stick well with me, you might want to edit that.

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR I stressed the human part because humans are the most successful predator on this planet.  We not only survive, but thrive in probably the broadest range of environments possible.  Almost all other predators I can think of, no matter how successful in their own environments, tend to be highly specialized and cannot transition to another environment.  A polar bear will not thrive in the Mojave desert.  That is precisely why I stress a foundation on the listed human qualities that made us the apex predator wherever we go.

Comment: I would understand if you went with a creature with the intelligence of a raven or a dolphin. But humans have no prominent natural weapons no protection against the environment. Humans solely rely on their tools to get the job done. Not exactly what I'm looking for with my creature.

Comment: I did forget to add a pelt.  I did however give the creature claws and jaws, both very common in the natural world, along with greater speed granted by the dog or catlike shape of the leg.  The endurance part is the largest key, granted by the deep chest and concomitant lung capacity.  With teeth, claws, and endurance these guys should do well even without getting to the point of tool use, but that would make them even more terrifying. Edited to add the pelt

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR did a couple of edits to make it a bit more clear.  Better?